# Object tag is not working

Tags: html

I want to use the HTML tag to play the
 video file in my browser. I have tried
 with object tag as well as embed tag.
 Both the things are not working for
 me. When I was using object tag my
 browser screen got flickering but the
 video is not playing.

Is there any way
 way to solve the problem? How can play
 the video file in browser?

My code:

```
<html>
<object data="flash.mpeg" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="550">
        <param name="MOVIE" value="flash.mpeg">
</object>
</html>
```

Comment: You are specifying flash, yet the source is a mpeg. Isn't that contradictory?

Comment: Is it a shockwave flash file or an MPEG file? Make up your mind. Considering the file name, it looks like it's an MPEG—you should be using `video/mpeg` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate mime type for MPEG video is "video/mpeg". Try that instead of "application/x-shockwave-flash" and it should work, provided you have the appropriate codec installed.

Comment: I have changed the type as "video/mpeg" after that also it didn't get work. I have same problem as before. Can you give any other way to resolve it?

Comment: Try a different machine, or try a different browser on the same machine, in case your current setup does not support video. Add <body> tags to your html file to make sure the video is visible.

Comment: Yeah..Thank you so much. It worked fine in firefox-3.5 version.It didn't work in firefox 2.0.0.19 version. Without body tag also it worked fine. Once again thanks...

Comment: One more question. I want to load the video file as like "youtube" video screen. It should have play button , pause , volume adjustment all those things.like a media player screen. How can I do that? If I click the play button then only the video should play otherwise wont.

Comment: The actual user interface depends on the plugin that the user has installed for that particular file type. If  you want more control over that, you might try a website like Vimeo -- once you have your video uploaded on there you can embed their flash player. IIRC, they offer some options regarding what the player will look like.