# Stop Magento/tinyMCE forcing object tag type

Tags: magento, object, types, tinymce

So iv been reading about peoples problems with tiny MCE "messing up" code. I understand it isn't, but I have a very minor problem that is become a major problem.

Im trying to add a simple object tag to one of my CMS pages. I need the object type to be "text/html" but whenever I save the page it converts this to "application/x-shockwave-flash"

I don't want to turn off the tinyMCE cleanup option as by the sounds of things this is a really bad thing to do.

So is there a way to stop it changing just the type attribute?

I have tried adding the code to a CMS widget and adding the widget to the page but this get the same altered result.

This thread ([Object tag is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743599/object-tag-is-not-working)) seems similar, but simply changing the type isn't working for me as it is automatically changing back to flash upon save.

The url i am trying to load looks like this...

(http://www.domain.com/animations/embed/one/o-t-t-d?player_width=100%&player_height=100%) I have been told that this will return flash if it is available or html if not.

Im assuming that because i'm saving the page on a PC with flash available its recognising and changing the type.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file `js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js` to make this happen.

Look for the settings array (around line 100). Add 'extended_valid_elements' there, like this;

```
var settings = {
    ...
    extended_valid_elements: 'object[type]',
    ...
};
```

This way, TinyMCE will know the type attribute is valid and won't change it.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! I will try this when I get home and apply my accepted answer :) Thank You!

Comment: Was this eventually the answer?

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately not :( this didn't seem to affect the version I was running. Iv since been exploring different editors.